# Using dynamic IDs in a string in a VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using a UIKit library for a tab component that listens to a `uk-tab` property that targets an id. The problem with this, is that it creates the same ID for every tabbed component. I like the UI, but whoever thought of this, didn't think too far into it. I could fix it by making the id dynamic but I am having trouble calling it in the uk-tab property because it is rendering a string. Coming from a react background, I would do a string literal and some JSX, something like `#item-${_id}`to show #item-12, #item-13....and so on. But That's not working. How can I do this in Vue?

Here is an example of how it works

```
<div class="mytrigger">
    <ul uk-tab="connect: #component-tab-left; animation: uk-animation-fade">
</div>
<div class="mytargetedtab">
    <ul id="component-tab-left" class="uk-switcher">
</div>
```

Here is an example of how what I need

```
<div class="mytrigger">
    <ul uk-tab="connect: #_uid+'switcher'; animation: uk-animation-fade">
</div>
<div class="mytargetedtab">
    <ul :id="_uid+'switcher'" class="uk-switcher">
</div>
```

Check out the dev tools. It should be 810switcher, but instead is taking it as a string 
[image]

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I think you are almost there, just put `:` before `uk-tab` and your `_uid` will get bind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you need is:

```html
<ul :uk-tab="`connect: #${_uid}switcher; animation: uk-animation-fade`">
```

Or if you prefer not to use backticks:

```html
<ul :uk-tab="'connect: #' + _uid + 'switcher; animation: uk-animation-fade'">
```

The output will be:

```html
<ul uk-tab="connect: #22switcher; animation: uk-animation-fade">
```

A few notes:

1. Using a `:` is short for `v-bind:` but don't let the name confuse you. `v-bind` doesn't necessarily bind anything, it just makes the attribute value a JavaScript expression.
2. I'd avoid using numbers at the start of element ids, I've seen that cause problems in the past. It'd be better to put the numbers at the end.
3. The underscore at the start of `_uid` indicates that it's private to Vue. There are no guarantees about what form it will take or whether it will even exist going forward.

Comment: This is it! It did exactly what I was looking for, however to my surprise, Both elements need the same id of component-tab-left for it to work because it's treating it as a css class, ::facepalm:: And then according to that id it ads a uk-active class with Javascript somewhere within their core files. sigh. Nevertheless, your solution worked for what I asked. Too sad it didn't actually solve the problem tho.

Answer (score 1):

Use `data-uk-tab` instead of `uk-tab` like below.

```
<div class="mytrigger">
    <ul data-uk-tab="{connect: `#${_uid}switcher`, animation: 'uk-animation-fade'}">
</div>
<div class="mytargetedtab">
    <ul :id="_uid+'switcher'" class="uk-switcher">
</div>
```

For more information => [Switcher with tabs](https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/switcher.html#switcher-with-tabs)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [any javascript expression](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Using-JavaScript-Expressions) in a data binding in vue.  So, if you bind a string template to the attribute, it'll populate what you expect.

```
<ul :uk-tab="`connect: #${uid}switcher`'; animation: uk-animation-fade">
```